# how to import data to my database using my same database on my pc?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, synchronization

I have a website that written by django and also same django code on my pc. you call the website www.mywebsite.com and my localhost on my pc is www.127.0.0.1.com, I use the same database model object for two database but I don't want to change my website's database by www.mywebsite.com/admin. I prefer change database on my pc that is www.127.0.0.1.com/admin and update my website by output of that. I should note that I use postgresql with same table and field for both. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: You are trying to change your development database and reflect that to production ?! Does that run once or all the time?

Comment: all time. for example at the end of each day, I want to update my database of website by output of database on my personal computer.

Comment: You could just create a crontab and dump the database to a file, then transfer the file to your site and load it.

Comment: Then I'm curious how do you do the development. If you generate test data, is it ended up being in your site? I honestly think you should separate development environment and production environment, unless you are collecting data related only to your personal pc.

Comment: my problem is every time I want to update database, it raises error because of same id in some data, and I will have to delete entire database and import data again. I want to update database in a way that if a data was there, ignore it and update new data.

Comment: For sure, you couldn't insert duplicate data. Then write an api on your site and push the data through api. In your api you need logic to handle duplications.